# Issues starting mongodb instance via mongodb shell

Tags: mongodb

I entered `sudo service mongod start` in my MongoDB shell (Ubuntu)
got the following error:

```
[js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:5
```

Any advice?

Comment: Check if in **/data** or **/data/db** you have `mongod.conf` (similar configuration file)

Comment: look at the end of the log file at /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log